# Unity stack game c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to recreate the Stack game where you stack square slices on top of each other and get it higher and higher. What's supposed to happen is the when the screen is clicked the square piece should stop at its current position and then a new square piece should spawn on top of it. Like so:

[Optimal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kraOd.png)

However, this is what the game is doing on my end.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkFBm.png)

[Current Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypH5N.png)

The square piece spawns and is placeable. However, the next square piece spawns on the same Y-axis as the previous piece instead of spawning on top of the previous piece. From there it overlaps the previous pieces. Heres the scripts that have been written so far. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? Specifically how to get the script to get the optimal output as pictured above?

**CubeSpawner.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]     
    private MovingCube cubePrefab;

    public void SpawnCube()
    {
        var cube = Instantiate(cubePrefab);

        if (MovingCube.LastCube != null && MovingCube.LastCube.gameObject != GameObject.Find("Start"))
        {
        cube.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
            MovingCube.LastCube.transform.position.y + cubePrefab.transform.localScale.y,
            transform.position.z);
        }
        else
        {
            cube.transform.position = transform.position;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, cubePrefab.transform.localScale);
    }
}
```

**GameManager.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) //if play presses left-click, control, tap a screen etc
        {
            if (MovingCube.CurrentCube != null)
                MovingCube.CurrentCube.Stop();

            FindObjectOfType<CubeSpawner>().SpawnCube();
        }
    }
}
```

**MovingCube.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static MovingCube CurrentCube { get; private set; }
    public static MovingCube LastCube { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField] //allows variable to be adjustable during runtime
    private float MoveSpeed = 1f;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (LastCube == null)
            LastCube = GameObject.Find("Start").GetComponent<MovingCube>(); 

        CurrentCube = this;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = GetComponentRandomColor();

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(LastCube.transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, LastCube.transform.localScale.z);

    }

    private Color GetComponentRandomColor()
    {
        return new Color(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1f));
    }

    internal void Stop()
    {
        MoveSpeed = 0;
        float hangover = transform.position.z - LastCube.transform.position.z;

        float direction = hangover > 0 ? 1f : -1f;
        SplitCubeOnZ(hangover, direction);
    }

    private void SplitCubeOnZ(float hangover, float direction)
    { 
        float newZSize = LastCube.transform.localScale.z - Mathf.Abs(hangover);
        float fallingBlockSize = transform.localScale.z - newZSize;

        float newZPosition = LastCube.transform.position.z + (hangover / 2);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, newZSize);
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, newZPosition);

        float cubeEdge = transform.position.z + (newZSize / 2f * direction);
        float fallingBlockZPosition = cubeEdge + fallingBlockSize / 2f * direction;

        SpawnDropCube(fallingBlockZPosition, fallingBlockSize);
    }

    private void SpawnDropCube(float fallingBlockZPosition, float fallingBlockSize)
    {
        var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, fallingBlockSize);
        cube.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, fallingBlockZPosition);

        cube.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        Destroy(cube.gameObject, 1f);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed; //moves the square piece
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code changes the last cube after stop, so you may add it.

```
internal void Stop()
{
    ...

    MovingCube.LastCube = MovingCube.CurrentCube;
}
```

Comment: I try adding that line of code in GameManager.cs and I get the error: 

"The property of indexer 'MovingCube.LastCube' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessable"

Comment: Sorry, you can put it in the end of Stop method, please check the update

Comment: I added that line of code and the same current output is happening.

Comment: Did you remove the line in Update method?

Comment: Which line are you referring too?

Comment: The line before I edit the answer between Stop and SpawnCube. now I move it from `GameManager.Update` into `MovingCube.Stop`.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what the changes were? Exactly what line to remove in the Update method?